# Using XPATH in python etree to select node with out a specific attribute

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

Following is my xml file contents,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" distance="500"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Following is my code,

```
tree = ET.parse(fileName)
doc = tree.getroot()

#nodes = doc.findall(".//country/neighbor") #works
#nodes = doc.findall(".//country/neighbor[@direction]") #works
nodes = doc.findall(".//country/neighbor[not(@direction)]") #not working
```

I am getting the following error,

`File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 363, in find
    return ElementPath.find(self, path, namespaces)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 285, in find
    return iterfind(elem, path, namespaces).next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 263, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 224, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate`

Comment: It could be that the not() function is not supported in the Python implementation. The documentation does not show any support for functions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support

Comment: Fine, then any idea on how to select nodes without a particular attribute ?

Comment: If functions are not supported at all I am almost convinced it is impossible. How about the `count()` function?

Comment: @MathiasMüller `nodes = tree.findall(".//country/neighbor[count(@direction) = 0]")` This didn't work either. Or am I using count wrong?

Comment: No, you are using it correctly. Then, I think it is clear that XPath functions cannot be used with elementtree - and I do not think you can test for the absence of attributes on elements with path expressions. But perhaps with other elementtree or Python functions?

Answer (score 2):

ElementTree only supports a subset of XPath 1.0. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support. Functions such as `not()` or `count()` do not work.

Here is how you can select `neighbor` elements that don't have a `direction` attribute without using XPath:

```
tree = ET.parse(fileName)

for n in tree.iter('neighbor'):  
    if not(n.get('direction')):  # If the element has no 'direction' attribute...
        print n.get('name')      # then print the value of the 'name' attribute
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xmlD = etree.parse('xmlTest.xml')
root = xmlD.getroot()

for child in root:
    for children in child:
        print(children.text)
```

Comment: You should properly format your code and add some explanation on how this solves the original problem.